# How to transform List<String> to Map<String,String> with Google collections?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, guava

I have a list of strings and I have a function to generate a value for each key in the list.

I want to create a map using this function. Can I do this with Google collections?

Comment: I assume you know this, but if the value the function generates could be the same for any two elements in the original list, you'd need to use `Multimaps.index` to generate a `Multimap` that can store multiple values for the same key.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of 7/26/2012, Guava master contains two new ways to do this. They should be in release 14.0.

`Maps.asMap(Set<K>, Function<? super K, V>)` (and two overloads for `SortedSet` and `NavigableSet`) allows you to view a `Set` plus a `Function` as a `Map` where the value for each key in the set is the result of applying the function to that key. The result is a view, so it doesn't copy the input set and the `Map` result will change as the set does and vice versa.

`Maps.toMap(Iterable<K>, Function<? super K, V>)` takes an `Iterable` and eagerly converts it to an `ImmutableMap` where the distinct elements of the iterable are the keys and the values are the results of applying the function to each key.

Answer (score 88):

Use [Maps.uniqueIndex(Iterable, Function)](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#uniqueindex) :

> Returns an immutable map for which the
>   Map.values() are the given elements in
>   the given order, and each key is the
>   product of invoking a supplied
>   function on its corresponding value.[(from javadoc)](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#uniqueIndex(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function))

Example:

```
Map<String,String> mappedRoles = Maps.uniqueIndex(yourList, new Function<String,String>() {
  public String apply(String from) {
    // do stuff here
    return result;
  }});
```

Comment: What is the performance of this solution? I would like to use it for 50,000+ elements in a list of large objects. I currently use two separate maps, that store the same objects, but mapped to different keys. I'd like to get rid of these maps and use a list (since the keys are already fields of the object). And your solution allow me to generate the maps automatically from the list. But at what cost?

Comment: @m_pGladiator I know your question is old, but the answer might interest other people... I would say the Guava methods are provided more for convenience / readability than for performance, in general. If you have a doubt, just stick to manually crafted loop. Or use a tool like Caliper to measure respective performances.

Comment: The OP says they have "a [function] to generate value for each key in the list". Maps.uniqueIndex generates key for each value in the list, which is the reverse of what the OP asked for. therefore this answer and Sean's asnwer are incorrect and ColinD's answer is.

Answer (score 15):

EDIT: It's entirely possible that Sean's right and I misunderstood the question.

If the original list is meant to be *keys*, then it sounds like you might be able to just use a computing map, via [`MapMaker.makeComputingMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/14.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#makeComputingMap(com.google.common.base.Function)), and ignore the input list to start with. **EDIT: As noted in comments, this is now deprecated and deleted in Guava 15.0.** Have a look at [`CacheBuilder`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) instead.

On the other hand, that also doesn't give you a map which will return null if you ask it for a value corresponding to a key which wasn't in the list to start with. It also won't give you In other words, this may well *not* be appropriate, but it's worth consideration, depending on what you're trying to do with it. :)

I'll leave this answer here unless you comment that *neither* approach here is useful to you, in which case I'll delete it.

---

**Original answer**

Using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) you can do this pretty easily with [`Maps.uniqueIndex`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#uniqueIndex(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function)):

```
Map<String, String> map = Maps.uniqueIndex(list, keyProjection);
```

(I mentioned Guava specifically as opposed to Google collections, as I haven't checked whether the older Google collections repository includes `Maps.uniqueIndex`.)

Comment: `makeComputingMap` is deprecated, and scheduled for deletion soon. http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/MapMakerMigration

Comment: @ripper234: Thanks, have added a link to CacheBuilder.

Comment: I thought about adding a link in my original comment, but is getting a Map out of CacheBuilder straightforward?

Answer (score 13):

Either I have misunderstood you or the other posters have. I understand that you want your list to be the map keys, while [`Maps.uniqueIndex()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#uniqueIndex%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) creates keys to map to your values (which is quite the opposite).

Anyway, there is an [open Guava issue](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=56) that requests the exact functionality you are requesting, and I have also [implemented such a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869258/guava-setk-functionk-v-mapk-v/3870481#3870481) for a previous question.

Comment: Yup, I think you may be right. I've edited my answer to mention computing maps, in case that would suit the OP, but I'm very ready to delete the answer completely.

Answer (score 6):

Using Guava + Lambda

```
 Map<String, YourCustomClass> map = Maps.uniqueIndex(YourList, YourCustomClass -> YourCustomClass.getKey());
```

Comment: If lambda are available, you could just drop guava and use Java8 stream API.

Comment: Unless you are developing for Android < 7.0