# Convert a set to map in java

Tags: java, guava

I have a set and I want to convert it to map in order to use it later in guava's `Maps.difference()`. I only care about the keys in the difference.
Came up with this version:

```
private <T> Map<T, T> toMap(Set<T> set) {
  return set.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), Function.identity()));
}
```

However, I know that usually, a set has a backing field of map. This is the method I use to create the map:

```
public static <E> Set<E> newConcurrentHashSet() {
  return Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<E, Boolean>());
}
```

Since I only need the keys I thought maybe I can get a view of this field somehow. any idea?

Comment: why not use https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference-java.util.Set-java.util.Set- ? Why are you trying to force a set into a map?

Comment: I would like to know which items only on left, which only on right, which in common (similar to map difference)

Comment: If you only need the keys, why are you converting to Map? A Map is basically a Set with values, so what you're saying makes no sense.

Answer (score 29):

I ended up with a fairly straight-forward one line solution with Java 8 as follows:

```
Map<String, Foo> map = fooSet.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getKey, e -> e));
```

- fooSet is a set of objects of type Foo, i.e. `Set<Foo> fooSet`
- Foo has a getter called `getKey` which returns a String

Answer (score 5):

Improvement of [developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4385895/developer)'s answer:

```
Map<String, Foo> map = fooSet.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getKey, Function.identity()));
```

or if you statically import `Collectors.toMap` and `Function.identity`:

```
Map<String, Foo> map = fooSet.stream().collect(toMap(Foo::getKey, identity()));
```

Comment: What is `Function.identity()`?

Comment: @jumping_monkey `Function.identity()` is documented at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--
It returns a function that accepts one argument and which returns that argument when called. In the `collect` example the effect is that the values of the stream of entries are taken as is to construct the map.

Comment: Oh, f(x) = x. Thanks Björn!

Answer (score 4):

You can convert a `Set` to a `Map` (same key and value taken from elements of `Set`) as shown below:

```
private <T> Map<T, T> toMap(Set<T> set) {
    Map<T, T> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    set.forEach(t -> map.put(t, t));//contains same key and value pair
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42921312/how-to-convert-a-set-to-map#comment72940545_42921312):

> I would like to know which items only on left, which only on right, which in common (similar to map difference)

Use [`removeAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) and [`retainAll()][3]`.

Example:

```
Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,3,5,7,9));
Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(3,4,5,6,7));

Set<Integer> onlyIn1 = new HashSet<>(set1);
onlyIn1.removeAll(set2);

Set<Integer> onlyIn2 = new HashSet<>(set2);
onlyIn2.removeAll(set1);

Set<Integer> inBoth = new HashSet<>(set1);
inBoth.retainAll(set2);

System.out.println("set1: " + set1);
System.out.println("set2: " + set2);
System.out.println("onlyIn1: " + onlyIn1);
System.out.println("onlyIn2: " + onlyIn2);
System.out.println("inBoth : " + inBoth);
```

*Output*

```
set1: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
set2: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
onlyIn1: [1, 9]
onlyIn2: [4, 6]
inBoth : [3, 5, 7]
```

---

Now, if you want to know all values and where they were found, you can do this (Java 8):

```
Set<Integer> setA = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,3,5,7,9));
Set<Integer> setB = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(3,4,5,6,7));

Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Integer i : setA)
    map.put(i, "In A");
for (Integer i : setB)
    map.compute(i, (k, v) -> (v == null ? "In B" : "In Both"));

System.out.println("setA: " + setA);
System.out.println("setB: " + setB);
map.entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output*

```
setA: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
setB: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
1=In A
3=In Both
4=In B
5=In Both
6=In B
7=In Both
9=In A
```

Answer (score 0):

See similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003832/how-to-transform-liststring-to-mapstring-string-with-google-collections).

Assuming that your original set is a set of values (no keys in original data!), you will need to specify keys for the newly created map. Guava's `Maps.uniqueIndex` might be helpful (see [here](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#uniqueIndex-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Function-))

Otherwise, if your original set is a set of keys (no values in original data!) that you want to retain, you will need to specify default or specific values for the newly created map. Guava's `Maps.toMap` might be helpful here. (See more [here](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#toMap-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Function-))

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Set<Foo> s = new HashSet<>();
        s.add(new Foo("cccc"));
        s.add(new Foo("aaaa"));
        s.add(new Foo("bbb"));
        Map<String, Foo> m = s.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getKey, Function.identity()));
        System.out.println(m);
    }
}

class Foo {
    String name;
    Foo(String name){this.name = name;}
    String getKey() {return name;}
}
```

#### Important note from the [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-):

> The returned Collector is not concurrent. For parallel stream
> pipelines, the combiner function operates by merging the keys from one
> map into another, which can be an expensive operation. If it is not
> required that results are inserted into the Map in encounter order,
> using toConcurrentMap(Function, Function) may offer better parallel
> performance.