# Does guava have a method for turning an iterable into a map of unique types?

Tags: java, guava

I could not find a method in guava that converts a Collection (or Iterator/Iterable) to a Map, something like the following (wildcards omitted for clarity):

```
public static <T, K, V> Map<K,V> collectionSplitter(Collection<T> source, Function<T,K> kProducer, Function<T,V> vProducer){
    Map<K,V> map = Maps.newHashMap();
    for(T t : source){
        map.put(kProducer.apply(t), vProducer.apply(t));
    }
    return map;
}
```

Is any existing method that does this? The closest I could find is Splitter.keyValueSplitter(), if T is a String.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Guava: Set<K> + Function<K,V> = Map<K,V>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869258/guava-setk-functionk-v-mapk-v)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The closest I'm aware of is [`Maps.uniqueIndex`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#uniqueIndex%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) - that does the key side, but not the value side... is that close enough?

You could potentially use:

```
Map<K, V> map = Maps.transformValues(Maps.uniqueIndex(source, kProducer),
                                     vProducer);
```

Slightly awkward, but it would get the job done, I think...

Comment: Yep, that worked for this case, though I wonder how flexible it is with the types.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Skeet mentioned, [Maps.uniqueIndex](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#uniqueIndex%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) is currently the closest thing to what you are looking for.

There are also a few requests for what you are looking for in the issue tracker, which you might want to "star" if you are interested in the suggested function:

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=56

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=460

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=679

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=718

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the java8 stream api

```
Map<Object, Object> map = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
                         .collect(Collectors.toMap(obj -> toKey(obj), 
                                                   obj -> toValue(obj)));
```